# How to edit Google Chrome page context menu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, context-menu

I would like to remove some items from the webpage context menu in Google Chrome (like 'Open in new window', 'Search with Google` etc.). How can I do it? Is there any extension which could help me?

Comment: Did you not find any yourself? Or was there something wrong with what you found?

Comment: I haven't found any extension, which could just edit the menu (used `context menu edit` as search string).

Answer (score 2):

While most sources state clearly that Google does not offer a way to remove Context Menu entries, there in the ChromeAPI documentation there is reference to `chrome.contextmenus` which includes `remove` and `removeall` arguments.

I would guess that this still only allows this call to remove entries belonging to the plugin which has this call, allowing plugins more flexibility in which options they show and when. But it is possible that this allows control of the entire menu. I just cannot find specific documentation spelling out which of these in the case.

Either way, there does not appear to be, at this time, an extension or other utility which allows removal of Google Chrome context-menu entries besides those belonging to plugins/extensions, and the only way to do that is if the plugins/extensions support this option themselves, or by removing the plugins/extensions themselves.

Comment: So no way to remove the annoying "copy link to highlight" either?

Comment: And no way to remove the "close other tabs" surprise bomb trap (for those of us who keep many tabs open).